# How can Kazakiri Hyouka appear in a photograph but not be seen in surveillance camera footage?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index

As we know about [Kazakiri Hyouka](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Kazakiri_Hyouka), nobody has seen her and knows about her appearance.In **episode 21 at 16:15**, Yomikawa tries to confirm the existence of the 2nd outsider with Tsukuyomi Komoe. Later, in **episode 22 14:25**  Tsukuyomi Komoe states that Hyouka didn't appear on any surveillance cameras in the school, but later, in Game Center, she appears in a photograph taken in the photo booth, with Index. It might be possible because she manifested in the real world when she touched Index. But she should have before after that, while getting leaving the school.

Tsukuyomi Komoe does say that nobody knows how she entered the school, but doesn't talk about how she got out without appearing on camera. But Yomikawa's question does imply that she didn't appear at all.

Yomikawa might have viewed all the footage and looked for info about the outsiders but didn't find anything on Kazakiri Hyouka.

So why wasn't she seen in the surveillance camera footage after she manifested in the real world?

Comment: Okay, I gotta sleep... So... Could ya add some citations via the [Funimation Subs / Dubs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2rR88FVc5Bk)? 'Cause the I can't find any mention of Surveillance Cameras and Hyouka in the [Wiki page on her Arc](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Kazakiri_Hyouka_Arc)...

Comment: @Malandy i added the episode and time.

Comment: @Malandy i really appreciate your edit but the YouTube video is not available in my region and i think time and episode are enough.

Comment: Oh... Sorry! ... I could try and find screenshots, or make them... *shrugs* ... Hope you get an answer you like!

Answer (score 2):

Well, she's unstable, so her qualities change every once in as while, making it possible that she was observable by a surveillance camera at one point and not another...

Surveillance cameras may also work differently from photographs, making her able to be seen in the latter, even if her qualities were the same.

Lastly, the surveillance cameras are likely monitored by Aleister, especially the ones in **That School**, and he erased Hyouka's presence because he didn't want her revealed or something, but a photo camera isn't connected, and so he can't hide her presence there.

---

If your question is "Why didn't Yomikawa find any info on Hyouka?", perhaps its just because there was no information to find. She's totally new. There wouldn't be much, if any information on her generated in less than a day out in public?

Comment: no, your 1st answer did tried to answer my question but not completely, and about Aleister, i need more information which shows that camera monitoring is done by him, coz that is very small job for his post.

Comment: @mirroroftruth - How far in the series are you? Are you only working with the Anime? 'Cause more informative answers might need spoilers for the Light Novels. ... I think he'd be following Hyouka's movements 'cause she's so important, so he knows what cameras he'd need to hack, etc?

Comment: Yes, anime only. I don't mind spoiler.It will be enough if you can show that the information of footage provided to Yomikawa has benn tampered by Aleister

Comment: @mirroroftruth Aleister, as the ruler of Academy City, is in a position to monitor everything that goes in the city. In one point in the anime a character invading the city uses this fact to talk directly to him, knowing he would be monitoring all communications. Given his interest Touma it wouldn't be surprising if he was monitoring Touma's high school in particular. The anime also makes it clear that Hyouka herself is almost as important to Aleister's plans. The only problem with this theory is that I don't see why he would feel the need to erase the footage.

Comment: @RossRidge - Okay, so Komoe did check the security footage... Aleister likely wants to keep Hyouka sorta secret?

Comment: @RossRidge yeah, i agree that Aleister control everything but i just want the source which shows that Aleister do tamper the information, does not matter form which episode or season, must be canon.

Comment: @mirroroftruth I don't think you're going to find anything in the anime (and probably the light novels, but I haven't read them) that proves any of Malandy's three theories correct, or any other for that matter. It's entirely possible the anime added the photo booth scene as fan service without any consideration of the inconsistency it would produce. However it's easy enough to hand wave away. Given Hyouka's very unusual nature I think the simplest explanation is Malandy's first theory, that she changed from being invisible to cameras to being visible, is the most likely.

Comment: @RossRidge but that is not possible, as explained in anime, Hyouka does not know anything about her power and control it, which means 1st one is not possible(if it is theory), i don't know about the 2nd theory about surveillance camera and photograph unless explained about the way they work in different manner and the last which is the one tries to answer my question but the information is less

Comment: @mirroroftruth No one is saying she consciously was hiding from the security cameras. Just like how she involuntarily became visible and invisible to humans, she could have involuntarily became visible and invisible to cameras.